# Suspend mode not working on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, suspend

I have a Sony Vaio and cannot make the suspend mode to work on Ubuntu 13.04

I have checked all the configurations in power and the computer is supposed to suspend when I close the lid, but this does not happen. The computer continues to work.

When I open the lid the screen is black and the system is not resumed. I have to restart the computer again by shutting it down with the power key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Let us know if that question/answer helps.